# Homogeneous system of linear equations with structure

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations

I have a homogeneous system of linear equations $Ax = 0$. The matrix $A$ is of size $N$. For $\det(A) = 0$, the rank of the matrix $A$ is $N - 1$. I am interested in the case $\det(A) = 0$ and want to find $x$.

The matrix $A$ is given by

\begin{equation}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
b & c & & & & d \\
a & b & c & & & \\
 & a & b & c & & \\
 & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \\
 & & &a & b & c \\
e & & & & a & b
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}

with all unspecified elements equal to zero. The parameters $a, \ldots,e$ depend on some common model parameters. Thus, the system of linear equations $Ax = 0$ reads

\begin{align}
b x(1) + c x(2) + d x(N) &= 0, \quad (1)\\
a x(i-1) + b x(i) + c x(i+1) &= 0, \quad i = 2,3,\ldots,N-1, \quad (2)\\
e x(1) + a x(N-1) + b x(N) &= 0. \quad (3)
\end{align}

What is the approach to solving this system of equations?

My approach is the following. Substitute $x(i) = r^i$ in $(2)$ and divide by $r^{i-1}$ and find two roots that satisfy this equation and label them $r_1$ and $r_2$. Since the rank of $A$ is $N-1$ we have one free variable, which we can use to scale the eigenvector. Let us choose $x(1)$ to be the free variable. Should I now set

\begin{equation}
x(i) = (c_1 r_1^{i-1} + c_2 r_2^{i-1}) x(1)
\end{equation}

and find $c_1$ and $c_2$ from $(1)$ and $(3)$? However, setting $x(i)$ as above seems to make no sense for $i = 1$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: as the rank of this matrix N by N matrix is N -1, it has only one free variable , once you fix the free variable all other variables will have a definite value

Comment: @Ritz In (1), $x(0)$ should be $x(1)$ and, in (3), $x(N-2)$ should be $x(N)$. Till $x(i)=(c_1 r_{1}^{i}+c_2 r_{2}^{i})x(1)$, but I propose that you use $x(N)$ instead of $x(1)$. Put then $x(i)$ in fixed (1) and (3) and determine $c_1, c_2$.

Comment: @JankoBracic I solved it. Thank you. Since the rank of the matrix is $N-1$, I deleted equation $(3)$ and replaced it by $x(1) = x(1)$, which gives $x(1) = (c_1 + c_2)x(1)$ and yields $c_1 + c_2 = 1$ and then I use equation $(1)$. Note that I changed the definition of $x(i)$ in the original post.